# `gdb` not recognized as a command even when MSYS gdb is up to date

Tags: gcc, gdb, g++, mingw, msys2

I followed [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_installing-the-mingww64-toolchain) tutorial and installed Visual Studio Code, MSYS2 and MinGW. I added the path to my MinGW-w64 bin folder to the Windows PATH environment variable (C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin) and checked it was correct.
The tutorial asked me to run
`gcc --version g++ --version gdb --version` to check my MinGW installation. gcc and g++ run fine, but gdb is 'not recognized as an internal or external command.'

The tutorial said to install missing gdb packages from the MinGW-w64 toolset. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438406/gdb-not-a-recognized-command-windows-command-prompt)  and ran the command it suggests, `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb`, and my MSYS2 terminal showed it was already installed. However, my terminal still does not accept gdb as a recognized command.

Comment: Did you check if there is a `gdb.exe` somewhere in `c:\msys64`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76552264/what-are-msys2-environments-how-do-i-pick-one)

Answer (score 0):

If you follow exactly the tutorial. I think this is the correct code `pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gdb`.